# Python str.contains function related to other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table that includes `title`, `genre` columns, and I need to change `genre` columns if `title` columns have a word `blue`. But the thing is I have many blue names in title, so I want to change only a specific `genre` type. ex:

```
title     genre                       title      genre
blue      x                           blue        x
red       x          ------->         red         x
blue      y                           blue        ychanged
red       y                           red         y
```

I used this but this function changed all `genre` if `title` has blue

```
df['genre'][df.title.str.contains('blue')] = 'ychanged'
```

How can I make a specific `str.contains`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `&`

```
df.loc[df.title.str.contains('blue') & df.genre.isin(['y']), 'genre'] = 'ychanged'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly index the desired rows using a logical expression like:

#### Code:

```
df.loc[df.title.str.contains('blue') & (df.genre == 'y'), 'genre'] = 'ychanged'
```

#### Test Code:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u"""
    title     genre  
    blue      x      
    red       x      
    blue      y      
    red       y      """), header=1)

print(df)

df.loc[df.title.str.contains('blue') & (df.genre == 'y'), 'genre'] = 'ychanged'

print(df)
```

#### Results:

```
  title genre
0  blue     x
1   red     x
2  blue     y
3   red     y

  title     genre
0  blue         x
1   red         x
2  blue  ychanged
3   red         y
```